# Why $\dot{H}^{s}(\mathbb{R}^{d})\subset L^{2}_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^{d}), s\in]0,1[$? from Bahouri-Chemin-Danchin book Fourier analysis and nonlinear pde

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis

Why $\dot{H}^{s}(\mathbb{R}^{d})\subset L^{2}_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^{d}), s\in]0,1[$? a detail from Bahouri-Chemin-Danchin book fourier analysis and nonlinear partial differential equations Page28, Proposition 1.37.

In this page, the authors say "In order to see that $u$ is in $L^{2}_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^{d})$, it is suffices to write $u=\mathscr{F}^{-1}(1_{B(0,1)}\hat{u})+\mathscr{F}^{-1}(1_{\mathbb{R}^{d}-B(0,1)}\hat{u}).$"

I'm so confused about this decomposition of $u$. If we want to prove this Proposition, we need to prove $$\int_{B(0,R)}u^{2}dx<\infty,\forall R>0.$$ According to authors' hint, we need to prove that $$\mathcal{F}^{-1}(1_{B(0,1)}\hat{u})\in L^{2}(B(0,R))$$ and  $$\mathcal{F}^{-1}(1_{B(0,1)^{c}}\hat{u})\in L^{2}(B(0,R)),$$ but what should we do next?

Comment: Then it follows that

$$ u = \mathcal{F}^{-1}\hat{u} = \mathcal{F}^{-1} [\mathbb{1}_{B(0,1)}\hat{u}] + \mathcal{F}^{-1} [\mathbb{1}_{B(0,1)^c}\hat{u}]  \in \mathrm{L}^2(B(0,R))$$

for all $R>0$. But this is equivalent to be in $\mathrm{L}^2_loc$, since for any compact $K\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ you can find an $R>0$ sufficiently large such that $K\subset B(0,R)$. Then the result holds easily since we have

$$ \lVert u \rVert_{\mathrm{L}^2(K)} \leqslant \lVert u \rVert_{\mathrm{L}^2(B(0,R))}.$$

Comment: @ToGle Thank you for your comments!!! You've helped me many times, and I don't know how to thank you. I wish you have a wonderful tomorrow!!!

Comment: but how to prove $\mathscr{F}^{-1}(1_{B(0,1)}\hat{u})\in L^{2}(B(0,R))$ and $\mathscr{F}^{-1}(1_{B(0,1)^{c}}\hat{u})\in L^{2}(B(0,R))$?

Comment: For the $B(0,1)$-part, you can write

$$\lVert \mathcal{F}^{-1}(1_{B(0,1)}\hat{u})\rVert_{\mathrm{L}^2(B(0,R))}\leqslant |B(0,R)|^\frac{1}{2} \lVert \mathcal{F}^{-1}(1_{B(0,1)}\hat{u})\rVert_{\mathrm{L}^\infty(B(0,R))} \leqslant C_R \lVert (1_{B(0,1)}\hat{u})\rVert_{\mathrm{L}^1(\mathbb{R}^n)}.$$

This is finite by the definition Bahouri, Chemin and Danchin chose.

Comment: Now, for the $B(0,1)^c$-part, you can write, by Fourier-Plancherel

$$\lVert \mathcal{F}^{-1}(1_{B(0,1)^c}\hat{u})\rVert_{\mathrm{L}^2(B(0,R))} \leqslant C\lVert 1_{B(0,1)^c}\hat{u}\rVert_{\mathrm{L}^2(\mathbb{R}^n)} \leqslant C\lVert \xi\mapsto|\xi|^s\hat{u}(\xi)\rVert_{\mathrm{L}^2(B(0,1)^c)}$$

The last inequality holds since $|\xi|\geqslant 1$. Finally, we can conclude

$$\lVert \mathcal{F}^{-1}(1_{B(0,1)^c}\hat{u})\rVert_{\mathrm{L}^2(B(0,R))} \leqslant C\lVert \xi\mapsto|\xi|^s\hat{u}(\xi)\rVert_{\mathrm{L}^2(\mathbb{R}^n)} = C\lVert u\rVert_{\dot{\mathrm{H}}^s(\mathbb{R}^n)}.$$

Comment: @ToGle Thank you for your answer. Thank you very much, I agree with your answer with both hands and feet！！！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, $u\in\dot{H}^s(\Bbb{R}^d)$ means $\hat{u}\in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Bbb{R}^d)$ and $\int_{\Bbb{R}^d}|\xi|^2|\hat{u}(\xi)|^2\,d\xi<\infty$. Let $B$ denote the unit ball.

- Since $\hat{u}$ is locally integrable, we have $1_{B}\hat{u}\in L^1(\Bbb{R}^d)$ and so its inverse Fourier transform $\mathcal{F}^{-1}(1_B\hat{u})$ is defined by the usual integral formula and it belongs to $C_0(\Bbb{R}^d)$ (continuous function which vanishes at infinity). In fact all we need is that this is a continuous function (which easily follows by dominated convergence) and so it is locally bounded and hence it belongs to $L^p_{\text{loc}}(\Bbb{R}^d)$ for all $1\leq p\leq\infty$, in particular for $p=2$.
- Next, $\int_{\Bbb{R}^d}|1_{B^c}\hat{u}|^2\,d\xi=\int_{B^c}|\hat{u}(\xi)|^2\,d\xi\leq\int_{B^c}|\xi|^2|\hat{u}(\xi)|^2\,d\xi\leq\int_{\Bbb{R}^d}|\xi|^2|\hat{u}(\xi)|^2\,d\xi<\infty$. I’m simply using the fact that if $\xi\in B^c$ then $1\leq |\xi|^2$, and then I’m trivially enlarging the domain of integration. This implies $1_{B^c}\hat{u}$ belongs to $L^2(\Bbb{R}^d)$, and since the Fourier transform is an isometry here, the inverse Fourier transform belongs to $L^2(\Bbb{R}^d)$ as well.

So, with this decomposition of $u$, we have actually shown that $\dot{H}^s(\Bbb{R}^d)\subset C_0(\Bbb{R}^d)+L^2(\Bbb{R}^d)\subset L^2_{\text{loc}}(\Bbb{R}^d)$, i.e every function in $\dot{H}^s$ can be written as a sum of a $C_0$ function and an $L^2$ function, and hence belongs to $L^2_{\text{loc}}(\Bbb{R}^d)$ (and hence by Holder’s inequality, you can also deduce, if you wanted, that it belongs to $L^p_{\text{loc}}$ for all $1\leq p\leq 2$).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The first point you mention is very insightful!!!